# Getting Operation System name from Get-VM

Tags: powershell, operating-system, virtual-machine, hyper-v

How can I get the Operating System name of a virtual machine from Hyper-V with PowerShell?

I tried with

```
get-vm
```

But this field is missing.

Comment: what about something like `get-vm | select *`

Comment: Yes. It display all informations of a vm but nothing about OS

Comment: I'm not sure if that information is even available from the "outside" of the VM. You could try something like [here](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/james/fun-with-powershell-hyper-v-virtual-machine-details/), i.e. using WMI to query "into" the running VM for that information - having the required permissions of course.

Comment: @Christian.K from looking that appears to be the only route I have seen as well. depending on your VM environment and the running guest types that is pretty bunk. Glad VMware provides guest OS properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Virtual Machine Manager, you are able to run something like 
    get-vm |ft Name, OperatingSystem
The data in VMM for operating system is usually correct, but it may show up as missing or incorrect in rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

This could be retrieved from guest intrinsic exchange items.

```
# Filter for parsing XML data
filter Import-CimXml 
{ 
   # Create new XML object from input
   $CimXml = [Xml]$_ 
   $CimObj = New-Object -TypeName System.Object 

   # Iterate over the data and pull out just the value name and data for each entry
   foreach ($CimProperty in $CimXml.SelectNodes("/INSTANCE/PROPERTY[@NAME='Name']")) 
      { 
         $CimObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $CimProperty.NAME -Value $CimProperty.VALUE 
      } 

   foreach ($CimProperty in $CimXml.SelectNodes("/INSTANCE/PROPERTY[@NAME='Data']")) 
      { 
         $CimObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $CimProperty.NAME -Value $CimProperty.VALUE 
      } 

   # Display output
   $CimObj 
} 

# Prompt for the Hyper-V Server to use
$HyperVServer = Read-Host "Specify the Hyper-V Server to use (enter '.' for the local computer)"

# Prompt for the virtual machine to use
$VMName = Read-Host "Specify the name of the virtual machine"

# Get the virtual machine object
$query = "Select * From Msvm_ComputerSystem Where ElementName='" + $VMName + "'"
$Vm = gwmi -namespace root\virtualization\v2 -query $query -computername $HyperVServer

# Get the KVP Object
$query = "Associators of {$Vm} Where AssocClass=Msvm_SystemDevice ResultClass=Msvm_KvpExchangeComponent"
$Kvp = gwmi -namespace root\virtualization\v2 -query $query -computername $HyperVServer

Write-Host
Write-Host "Guest KVP information for" $VMName

# Filter the results
try {
    $Kvp.GuestIntrinsicExchangeItems | Import-CimXml | where Name -eq "FullyQualifiedDomainName"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Not found"
}
```

From [Ben Armstrong’s Virtualization Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2008/11/18/hyper-v-script-looking-at-kvp-guestintrinsicexchangeitems/).